# How can I get html source from a request using The Grinder

Tags: python, jython, grinder

I have the following script:

```
  def page2(self):
  """GET / (request 201)."""
     result = request201.GET('/mypage/', None,
     ( NVPair('Accept', 'image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-   shockwave-flash, */*'), 
     NVPair('Accept-Language', 'en-us'), ))

# here i want to print the html source code from the result

return result
```

The script was recorded using the [Grinder Proxy](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
print result.text
```

See http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/script-javadoc/HTTPClient/HTTPResponse.html for additional detail.

Comment: I tried but this method is not working for all websites. For example:    result = request1.GET("http://www.accuweather.com/") when i call for result.text nothing is printed. Did I miss something?